# Частичная страница (_Partial) во вкладки (TAB)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Необходимо создать вкладки на подобии этих:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как их сделать?

Поиск в сети дал намек на необходимость использовать частичные страницы.
Если я все правильно понял то:

1. Делаю на странице вкладки:

```html
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active" id="class1">
            <a href="#tab_1_1" class="tbs" data-info="class1" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
                1 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class2">
            <a href="#tab_1_2" class="tbs" data-info="class2" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                2 класс
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="" id="class3">
            <a href="#tab_1_3" class="tbs" data-info="class3" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
                3 класс
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Вроде их сделать получилось:

[image: вроде начало есть]

2. Далее я пытаюсь через JS выполнить какую-нибудь инструкцию при кликании по вкладкам:

```js
    <script type="text/jscript">
        $('tbs').on('click', function () {
            console.log("Message!");
        });
    </script>
```

Но никакое сообщение в консоль не появляется при выборе вкладок.

Как мне при выборе соответствующей вкладки вызвать соответствующей ей информацию (частичное представление)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас маленькая ошибка в селекторе:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $('.tbs').on('click', function () {
        console.log("Message!");
    });
</script>
```

Если вы выбираете через класс то необходимо в начале название класса ставить точку - `.tbs`